# SQL group by: using where-clause logic to filter results based on aggregate functions

Tags: sql, mysql, where-clause

I have a basic group by/avg statement:

```
select url, avg(contentping+tcpping), count(*) from websites ws, ping pi 
where ws.idwebsite = pi.idwebsite and errortype is null
group by url order by avg(contentping+tcpping) asc;
```

What I want to do now is to drop any results which have a higher than average ping of 500. How can I do this...?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just add a `having` clause:

```
select url, avg(contentping+tcpping), count(*) from websites ws, ping pi 
where ws.idwebsite = pi.idwebsite and errortype is null
group by url 
having avg(contenetping+tcpping) < 500
order by avg(contentping+tcpping) asc;
```

Comment: Ah, what a refresher. Thanks.