# Show Records with Zero Count Using Where Statement

Tags: php, mysql

The following statement queries a table, which lists a list of employees who have taken an "AS" training session. Some employees have taken the "AS" training several times and may show up on the list multiple times.

```
SELECT schedule_test.ID, (COUNT(CASE WHEN schedule_test.Course LIKE 'AS%' 
THEN schedule_test.Course END)) AS "AS" 
FROM schedule_test
GROUP BY schedule_test.ID
```

[image]

I would like to now add a WHERE statement to only show the employees who have not taken an "AS" session, or to put it another way show employees that only have 0 "AS" sessions. I have tried:

```
WHERE "AS"==0 with no success. 
I even tried WHERE "AS" < 1 with no success.
```

Could use some help.

Comment: I think you mean HAVING, not WHERE.

Comment: *WHERE "AS"==0 with no success.* - remove one of the `=` signs. This isn't PHP, it's MySQL; *2 different animals here*. You need to show "where" you put that clause in your query. You may have not used it correctly. Plus, it could be a quoting method, where you're using `'` in one and `"` in the other.

Comment: Alvaro-I tried HAVING "AS" = 0 with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL group by: using where-clause logic to filter results based on aggregate functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480613/sql-group-by-using-where-clause-logic-to-filter-results-based-on-aggregate-func)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
HAVING count(course) < 1
```

At the end of your query

Comment: Success. Much thanks. I kept using HAVING  'AS' = 0. The solution was HAVING  (COUNT(CASE WHEN schedule_test.Course LIKE 'AS%' THEN schedule_test.Course END)) < 1. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3258571 you are welcome, please remember to mark the answer as the solution if it was useful :)

Comment: Please edit your answer so it is all inclusive. You solved it via a thread. May not make sense to the next person.

Comment: @user3258571 how was it solved via a thread? I don't understand

Comment: No problem. Will use your answer above. Thought the solution should include HAVING (COUNT(CASE WHEN schedule_test.Course LIKE 'AS%' THEN schedule_test.Course END)) < 1. Thanks again.

Comment: Ohhh, you mean to give an alias to the column?

Comment: Correct. I thought the alias in the correct answer would make it easier to read.